# Given rank and nullity, prove that $rank(B^2)=rank(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 &4 \\ 
 1&  -1&3 \\ 
 2& 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

We have $rank(B)=2$, $nullity(B)=1$, $ker(B)\;\cap \; col(B)=\left \{ \mathbf{0} \right \}$

Prove, without computing $B^2$, that $rank(B^2)=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** By the conditions, we have $\mathrm{col}(B)\oplus\ker(B) =\Bbb R^3$, and thus $B$ restricted to $\mathrm{col}(B)$ is injective.

Comment: Or just note that the kernel of the restriction of $B$ to $\operatorname{col}(B)$ is $\operatorname{ker}(B) \cap \operatorname{col}(B)$.